# VUE JS template compiling error just on IE11

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am facing a strange issue which take my 4 to 5 hours but i am still unable to find a solution.
The error is i am getting is my code is just working fine on chrome and firefox safari all browsers but when i am running it on IE11 it throw me this error:

> [Vue warn]: Error compiling template: `<div class="floating-chat lh-2-0" id="chat-app"> &nbsp;&nbsp; <span class="title pull-lef col-md-12"> <span class="chat-notification-icon" v-if="this.unreadChatOfUsersCount.count > 0"> {{this.unreadChatOfUsersCount.count}} </span> Messaging </span> <div class="pull-righ col-md-"> </div>`

Please someone give me a solution for this.

I converted my all methods from `method(){}` to method: `function(){}` also add polyfill but cant reach to result.

[image: This is the screenshot of my code]

Comment: If your question is related to vue then why are you adding reactjs and jquery tags?

Comment: Can you add the full error message?

Comment: And please show the template, since error is there...

Comment: [Vue warn]: Error compiling template:

<div class="floating-chat lh-2-0" id="chat-app">

    &nbsp;&nbsp;      <span class="title pull-lef col-md-12">
                        <span class="chat-notification-icon" v-if="this.unreadChatOfUsersCount.count > 0"> {{this.unreadChatOfUsersCount.count}} </span>
                        Messaging
                     </span>
    <div class="pull-righ col-md-">
    </div>

Comment: Please add your source as text, not a screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had such problem on my project. It can happen in case you are using IE incompatible code in the component template.

For me, it was string interpolation in the **href** attribute.